# Use recursive CTE to handle date logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

At work, one of my assignments is to calculate commission to the sales staff. One rule has been more challenging than the others.

Two sales teams A and B work together each selling different products. Team A can send leads to team B. The same customer might be send multiple times. The first time a customer (ex. lead 1)* is send a commission is paid to the salesperson in team A who created the lead. Now the customer is “locked” for the next 365 days (counting from the date lead 1 was created)*. Meaning that no one can get additional commission for that customer in that period by sending additional leads (ex. Lead 2 and 3 gets no commission).* After the 365 days have expired. A new lead can be created and receive commission (ex. Lead 4).  Then the customer is locked again for 365 days counting from the day lead 4 was created. Therefore, lead 5 gets no commission. The tricky part is to reset the date that the 365 days is counted from.

'* Reference to tables #LEADS and #DISERED result.

I have solved the problem in tSQL using a cursor, but I wonder if it was possible to use a recursive CTE instead. I have made several attempts the best one is pasted in below. The problem with my solution is, that I refer to the recursive table more than once. I have tried to fix that problem with nesting a CTE inside a CTE. That’s is not allowed. I have tried using a temporary table inside the CTE that is not allowed either. I tried several times to recode the recursive part of the CTE so that the recursive table is referenced only once, but then I am not able to get the logic to work.

I am using SQL 2008

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#LEADS', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #LEADS;

CREATE TABLE #LEADS (LEAD_ID INT, CUSTOMER_ID INT, LEAD_CREATED_DATE DATETIME, SALESPERSON_NAME varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #LEADS
VALUES   (1,    1,  '2013-09-01', 'Rasmus')
        ,(2,    1,  '2013-11-01', 'Christian')
        ,(3,    1,  '2014-01-01', 'Nadja')
        ,(4,    1,  '2014-12-24', 'Roar')
        ,(5,    1,  '2015-12-01', 'Kristian')
        ,(6,    2,  '2014-01-05', 'Knud')
        ,(7,    2,  '2015-01-02', 'Rasmus')
        ,(8,    2,  '2015-01-08', 'Roar')
        ,(9,    2,  '2016-02-05', 'Kristian')
        ,(10,   2,  '2016-03-05', 'Casper')

SELECT  *
FROM    #LEADS;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DISERED_RESULT', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #DISERED_RESULT;

CREATE TABLE #DISERED_RESULT (LEAD_ID INT, DESIRED_COMMISION_RESULT CHAR(3))
INSERT INTO #DISERED_RESULT
VALUES   (1, 'YES')
        ,(2, 'NO')
        ,(3, 'NO')
        ,(4, 'YES')
        ,(5, 'NO')
        ,(6, 'YES')
        ,(7, 'NO')
        ,(8, 'YES')
        ,(9, 'YES')
        ,(10, 'NO')

    SELECT  *
    FROM    #DISERED_RESULT;

WITH COMMISSION_CALCULATION AS
(
    SELECT  T1.*
            ,COMMISSION = 'YES'
            ,MIN_LEAD_CREATED_DATE AS COMMISSION_DATE
    FROM     #LEADS AS T1
    INNER JOIN  (
                SELECT  A.CUSTOMER_ID
                        ,MIN(A.LEAD_CREATED_DATE) AS MIN_LEAD_CREATED_DATE
                FROM    #LEADS AS A
                GROUP BY A.CUSTOMER_ID
                ) AS T2 ON T1.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID  AND T1.LEAD_CREATED_DATE = T2.MIN_LEAD_CREATED_DATE

UNION ALL

SELECT  T10.LEAD_ID
        ,T10.CUSTOMER_ID
        ,T10.LEAD_CREATED_DATE
        ,T10.SALESPERSON_NAME
        ,T10.COMMISSION
        ,T10.COMMISSION_DATE
FROM    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T5.CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY T5.LEAD_CREATED_DATE ASC) AS RN 
                ,T5.*
                ,T6.MAX_COMMISSION_DATE
                ,DATEDIFF(DAY, T6.MAX_COMMISSION_DATE, T5.LEAD_CREATED_DATE) AS ANTAL_DAGE_SIDEN_SIDSTE_COMMISSION
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T6.MAX_COMMISSION_DATE, T5.LEAD_CREATED_DATE) > 365      THEN 'YES'
                    ELSE 'NO'
                END AS COMMISSION
                ,CASE 
                    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T6.MAX_COMMISSION_DATE, T5.LEAD_CREATED_DATE) > 365      THEN T5.LEAD_CREATED_DATE
                    ELSE NULL
                END AS COMMISSION_DATE
        FROM        #LEADS AS T5
            INNER JOIN (SELECT      T4.CUSTOMER_ID
                                    ,MAX(T4.COMMISSION_DATE) AS MAX_COMMISSION_DATE
                        FROM        COMMISSION_CALCULATION AS T4
                        GROUP BY    T4.CUSTOMER_ID) AS T6   ON T5.CUSTOMER_ID = T6.CUSTOMER_ID
        WHERE   T5.LEAD_ID   NOT IN (SELECT LEAD_ID FROM COMMISSION_CALCULATION)
        ) AS T10
WHERE   RN = 1


)   
    SELECT  *
    FROM    COMMISSION_CALCULATION;
```

Comment: plus 1 for sample data,please post your expected result

Comment: The last column in the sample data is the desired result. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your query is having some issues,can you paste expected result in question

Comment: i have added a new table in the original questien with the desired result.

Comment: I'm confused by this statement. " If the second lead is created after 365 days of the first lead the customer gets commission. The second lead gets all commission the next 365 days."

Comment: I agree with DVT, can you please clarify the rules behind where the commission goes?

Comment: DVT, I am not surprised that you are confused, my description was not completely clear. I have rephrased the original question. I hope it makes the problem more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some assumptions where your description does not fully make sense as written, but the below achieves your desired result:

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#leads', 'u') is not null
drop table #leads;

create table #leads (lead_id int, customer_id int, lead_created_date datetime, salesperson_name varchar(20))
insert into #leads
values (1,    1,  '2013-09-01', 'rasmus')
      ,(2,    1,  '2013-11-01', 'christian')
      ,(3,    1,  '2014-01-01', 'nadja')
      ,(4,    1,  '2014-12-24', 'roar')
      ,(5,    1,  '2015-12-01', 'kristian')
      ,(6,    2,  '2014-01-05', 'knud')
      ,(7,    2,  '2015-01-02', 'rasmus')
      ,(8,    2,  '2015-01-08', 'roar')
      ,(9,    2,  '2016-02-05', 'kristian')
      ,(10,   2,  '2016-03-05', 'casper')

if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#disered_result', 'u') is not null
drop table #disered_result;

create table #disered_result (lead_id int, desired_commision_result char(3))
insert into #disered_result
values (1, 'yes'),(2, 'no'),(3, 'no'),(4, 'yes'),(5, 'no'),(6, 'yes'),(7, 'no'),(8, 'yes'),(9, 'yes'),(10, 'no')

with rownum
as
(
    select row_number() over (order by customer_id, lead_created_date) as rn                                -- This is to ensure an incremantal ordering id
            ,lead_id
            ,customer_id
            ,lead_created_date
            ,salesperson_name
    from #leads
)
,cte
as
(
    select rn
            ,lead_id
            ,customer_id
            ,lead_created_date
            ,salesperson_name
            ,'yes' as commission_result
            ,lead_created_date as commission_window_start
    from rownum
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select r.rn
            ,r.lead_id
            ,r.customer_id
            ,r.lead_created_date
            ,r.salesperson_name

            ,case when r.customer_id <> c.customer_id       -- If the customer ID has changed, we are at a new commission window.
                then 'yes'
                else case when r.lead_created_date > dateadd(d,365,c.commission_window_start)   -- This assumes the window is 365 days and not one year (ie. Leap years don't add a day)
                        then 'yes'
                        else 'no'
                        end
                end as commission_result

            ,case when r.customer_id <> c.customer_id
                then r.lead_created_date
                else case when r.lead_created_date > dateadd(d,365,c.commission_window_start)   -- This assumes the window is 365 days and not one year (ie. Leap years don't add a day)
                        then r.lead_created_date
                        else c.commission_window_start
                        end
                end as commission_window_start

    from rownum r
        inner join cte c
            on(r.rn = c.rn+1)
)
select lead_id
        ,commission_result
from cte
order by customer_id
        ,lead_created_date;
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make the solution. The solution provides the desired result. I look forward to implementing it in my commission calculation project so see how the performance is compared to my cursor based solution.